# Getting Waypoints between two coordinates from CloudMade

Tags: coordinates, cloudmade

Suppose I have A (source point) and B (destination point), then I want to get a series of route point or waypoints between A to B from CloudMade. The result that I need is something like this:

```
(LonA, LatA) (Lon1,Lat1) (Lon2,Lat2) (Lon3, Lat3)................(Lon_n, Lat_n) (LonB, LatB)
```

Are there any available methods or tools to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with this map application: http://maps.cloudmade.com/.

At first you create your route with waypoints. Click on the button "Get directions" (upper left corner) and create your route (clicking on the map). After that you can export (there is a button on the upper right corner) your route (include waypoints) to a gpx-or a json-file. You can load both files to a GIS.

[image: route with waypoints]